# Generalization of scalar product to multiple vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, products

Let's look at the scalar product of two vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$:

$$
\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \sum_ka_k \cdot b_k
$$

I'm working my way through some physics problems where I have terms of the following form popping up:

$$
\sum_k a_k \cdot b_k \cdot c_k \cdot \ldots
$$

This looks a little like a "generalization of the scalar product" to an arbitrary numbers of vectors to me. At the moment I'm making up my own notation by borrowing the "$\circ$" symbol from the Hadamard product to write

$$
\sum_ka_k \cdot b_k \cdot c_k \cdot \ldots = [ \mathbf{a} \circ \mathbf{b} \circ \mathbf{c} \circ \ldots ]
$$

where I'm using square brackets to imply summation over all elements. Since I also have to deal with powers of the elements in this sum, I mimick Hadamard powers that I've seen written with the same symbol:

$$
\sum_k a^\alpha_k \cdot b^\beta_k \cdot c^\gamma_k \cdot \ldots = [ \mathbf{a}^{\circ\alpha} \circ \mathbf{b}^{\circ\beta} \circ \mathbf{c}^{\circ\gamma} \circ \ldots ]
$$

However I would like to know if there is already an accepted way to represent a sum like the one above so I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel. In addition, so far I have only seen the Hadamard product defined for matrices, not vectors, so it's my working assumption that this would be acceptable use for the symbol as well.

(I guess I could write this as a series of multiplications of diagonal matrices, however it feels a bit like overkill to introduce matrices if I know that none of my terms will ever have two indices to them. That's more personal taste though.)

Comment: Dot your Hadamard product with the all-ones vector, i.e. $\;{\tt1}\cdot(a\circ b\circ c)$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, that would formally work. It if feels a bit like a "gotcha"... but I'll keep it in mind. Maybe I'll decide to go with "conciseness over correctness" (if that makes sense) and use square brackets like in my post to indicate summation over all elements. I'm really starting to clog up my expressions otherwise if I introduce more operations.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your interpretation of these products as a generalization of the scalar product. I assume that $a_k$, $b_k$, $c_k...$ are the Cartesian components of vectors $\vec a$, $\vec b$, $\vec c...$ (i.e. in some orthonormal basis). Now, the scalar product of two vectors:

$$ S = \sum_k a_k\,b_k$$

is independent of the Cartesian system of coordinates used, i.e. $S$ is truly a scalar; it is a property only of the two vectors  $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ used, and not of the coordinate system used. However, for three vectors $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec c$:

$$ Q = \sum_k a_k\,b_k\,c_k$$

is not a scalar. Its value depends on the Cartesian system of coordinates used. If $a'_k = \sum_jR_{kj}\,a_j$ are the Cartesian components of $\vec a$ in a rotated coordinate system ($R_{kj}$ are the elements of the rotation matrix), and similarly for $\vec b$ and $\vec c$, then in general:

$$ Q' =\sum_k a'_k\,b'_k\,c'_k \ne Q$$

Comment: Thanks! I see your point. It seems to come down to a definition of what a scalar is that I am not really aware of; I was going by a seeming similarity in the definition. - Actually, my "vectors" are in fact derivatives of a wavefunction with respect to each individual particle; i.e. the indices k refer to particle numbers in my physical system, not directly Cartesian components in space. Not sure if that changes anything. - Would it be fair to call it a "generalized inner product" though? Does that hinge on the same aspect?

Comment: I personally would not use words like scalar or inner product which refer to intrinsic properties of the vectors involved, and do not depend on the particular orthonormal basis use to describe them.

Comment: Alright. Hadamard product it is, then.